# how to refresh partial view without refreshing the complete page in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I m using a Ajax Tab panel in my application.
There are 4 tabs on Left hand side and a partial view on right hand side.
In each of these tab I m displaying some data and there is a select link button on each tab.
when I click on any of the select link button I m filling the partial view with some information.
When this happens my view is completly loaded again.
A   B    C   D

eg these are the tabs.
let us suppose that I m on tab B and now when I click on the select link button My view is completly loaded with information.
but the tab loose the focus at this point. I comes back to the default value.
so I want help on this 
1) either I have to refresh only the partial view without loading the complete page 
2) or I need to maintain active tab index value on click on select link button
Please help me with this problem 
and provide me examples

Comment: You should only refresh the partial view ,that is the advantage of MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery Tabs - Load contents only when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502391/jquery-tabs-load-contents-only-when-clicked)
 Here is the example which loading content of the tabs dynamically by Ajax. It is for PHP what you need to change is put controller/action instead of URL of the PHP page.

```
$.get("controller/action", {tab_clicked, "my_tab"}, tab_fetch_cb, "text/json/xml");
```

or else instead of Ajax.ActionLink

use  `<a onclick="LoadTab(@item.ID)">Item @item.ID</a>`
 and jquery function to change the tab and load data dyanamicaly

```
function LoadTab(id){
     //Change tab here Ex: $('#tabs').tabs('select', index);
      $.get('ajax/test.html', {Id, id},function(data) {
          $('#Partial_Controller_Name').html(data);

      });

}
```

Comment: Let me give u the code as well
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Select", "Partial_Controller_Name", new { Id = item.ID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Partial_Controller_Name" })%>
<div id="Partial_Controller_Name">
                <% Html.RenderPartial("Partial_Controller_Name"); %>
            </div>
When I click on this button the it redirect me partial_Controller_Name without view

Comment: Make sure you have added a reference to ajax javascript library <script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Try adding reference to Microsoft Ajax library                  <script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Write an ajax call on click event of tab and load the partial view in the container of the tab

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644350/asp-net-mvc-load-a-partial-view-using-ajax-from-a-jquery-ui-tab

Comment: But I cannot load the partial view in Tab.

Comment: write actionresult the return the partial view the other procedure is same as mentioned in above answer tabs are nothing but ul and li with some javascript

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using RjsResult class

if using mvc1 u can use [RjsResult.cs](http://www.brightmix.com/assets/2008/11/16/RjsResult.cs)

by this..you can update as many div you want in a page...

use this for implementation

```
public ActionResult Some_Method(){
RjsResult r = new RjsResult();
ViewData["SomeData"] = Some_Function();
r.update("DIV_id","PartialPagePath",ViewData,ControllerContext);
return r;
}
```

so when you click on somethink..this function will be implemnted and will refresh you div with tht partial

View part

```
<div id="DIV_id"></div>
```

you can update as many dv as you want with a single click :)